# Linux Kernel limit access to root with a button?

Tags: linux, kernel, security, root

Is it possible to limit the access to a root account from within the kernel?

I mean that if I press a button then the system detects the button being pressed and then allows access to the root account at boot. To me this could be useful to prevent a hacking attack from a bug of one of my programs that have an open port and maybe are vulnerable to attacks!

If I can limit the attacker's movement maybe I can restrict the information it can have access to not compromising sensitive data. Is there a special way of doing this? Permissions like how android manage access, a boot parameter or another kernel?

It is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything is usually possible with Linux/Unix but most of the time a break-in isn't coming through the front door by logging into the root account. The more typical vector of attack is that a process that is running with elevated privileges is targeted for attack and then a weakness in the applications functionality is determined, and exploited.

The more general approach is to not run your applications with such highly elevated privileges. You typically start the application up as root, but then fork another copy of the process as an alternative user.

Additionally a [`chroot` environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) is used to also limit exposure of the underlying filesystem.

If you go through the [Server Security Reference from Red Hat](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/sect-Security_Guide-Server_Security.html) it covers much of what I've mentioned in more detail if you're interested.

Comment: I know that's the reason I want to limit access to the root account at kernel loading time. The reason I want to do this is because if I sell the device I wanted to make it possible to give remote assistance but that the only way to make changes is to press the button and then reboot to control access of the device. Let's say it some type of recovery. Then at least use a server running a VPN or Proxy to redirect all traffic from the clients. I'm pretty focused on the security part because it's the most important part and I don't trust ISP or their employees.

Comment: Actually I'm considering the use of hacking methods in layers of security like banning clients from AP using MDk3, router's have flaws of security too. Reset the router and the rules are gone. I'll use the server to control access based on mac address but that is not enough. I use 5 layers of security to detect users because I know how easy is to stole information on common persons that know nothing about computer or about security. The problem is that there's no secure method at all, RFID can be hacked using an arduino nano & RFID Shield ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any existing implementation, but you could write a [PAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_Authentication_Modules) module that requires a button to be pressed.

However, this would only protect your system against malware that has somehow obtained the credentials you use to log in as root. For example, if you use `sudo` and type your password to execute commands as root, and some malware manages to grab your password, then that malware can run `sudo` without your detecting it. Requiring a button press would make this impossible.

This is just about useless. Malware that can do that could also piggyback the first time it sees you run `sudo` and plant something that runs with root privileges. That's not the most common attack vector: malware typically gains root permissions by exploiting a bug in the kernel or in a program that's running as root. This won't require a button press because as far as anyone can see, it's perfectly normal behavior: an already-running program doing what it's programmed to do. The fact that the program is executing attacker-supplied code instead of what it should be doing cannot be helped: the computer does what it's told, not necessarily what you'd like it to do.

Comment: That's a perfect solution but can it work at boot in early stages of boot and detected even when the system is up?? If so then I can program a module to reboot and run a script to change boot options?? Is there another way to accomplish this??